# C - What's more efficient, conditional variable wakeup vs thread pool launch

Tags: c, multithreading, memory, concurrency

I have a task that needs to be run on a different thread, that will read from disk. Which would be more efficient in terms of CPU cycles and disk reads? Which would be the most responsive/fast?

1.) Create a thread that waits on a conditional variable to wakeup the thread and run the task.

2.) Run a pool of threads busy waiting and just grab a thread from the pool when we need to run task.

Comment: Given that the thread is going to be doing I/O, the time will all be consumed by the I/O and it is largely immaterial which method you use to get a thread that can do the job.  What will you do if you run out of threads in the pool?

Comment: 'busy waiting'......why would you do that?